# postgresql разрыв соединения при вставке большого xml

Tags: xml, postgresql

postgresql поле с типом xml. в таблицу успешно добавляются данные через INSERT максимальное успешно вставленное поле размером около 2Mb, когда подходит вставить в базу строку, в которой размер поля ~12Mb получаю ошибку *Connection to the server has been lost*. Чем вставлять без разницы, php pg_insert или pg_query или даже записать запрос в файл и выполнить его через командную строку и psql. Если поменять тип поля на text то вставка проходит без проблем, но если потом сделать запрос типа select cast(my_field as xml) ... то тоже возникает *Connection to the server has been lost*. 
В чём может быть причина? В postgresql.conf смотрел, но подозрительных параметров не нашёл. Версия postgres — 10.5
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Мне сразу вспомнилось вот это вот обсуждение: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAFj8pRDZo4w0iunJ3z6Sh%3D0Lw2oOc9Hj%2BQTjUFnuyKdvY8Dzwg%40mail.gmail.com#c74d77d32e515bc8de5558ccc7dcd210 Какая ОС, проверьте в логах базы что происходит в действительности. Если я угадываю верно - то это известный баг libxml2 и со стороны базы не лечится.

Comment: @Мелкий спасибо за наводку. ОС centos7. глубоко не копнул, но там упоминается тот же файл из того же источника что и у меня. у него egrul/EGRUL_FULL_2018-01-01_X.XML, у меня egrul/EGRUL_2018-10-02_1.ZIP/EGRUL_2018-10-02_346536.XML
и да, в php они у меня парсились, только с включённой опцией HUGE.
Сейчас смигрировал базу на свежий релиз postgres 11,результат тот же